# Picker, tag, Equatable and assign problem

Tags: swiftui

I try to build quite complicated View, where everything depends on everything. Every change in lower part is immediately reflected in `Styles` Picker - names, values... *everything is connected*
[image]

And I found some chicken-egg problem I cannot solve.
To tag Picker selection I use object called `StyleInstance` which is `Equatable, Identifiable`.

```
extension StyleInstance {
    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
       lhs.id == rhs.id 
    }
}
```

I excluded every other property from `==` because every time I change one of them, Picker throws an error `the selection .... is invalid and does not have an associated tag, this will give undefined results.`

Generally it works. But in other place I have a function like this:

```
func updateStyles() {
        designSpace.styles.forEach({print ("I", $0.positionsOnAxes.map {$0.position})})
        styles = designSpace.styles
        styles.forEach({print ("O", $0.positionsOnAxes.map {$0.position})})
    }
```

And (surprise, surprise!) printed result is somehow wrong..

```
I [196.03959526783427, 181.2955586342863, 100.0]
I [175.6884102472529, 184.68257906057954, 900.0000000000001]
I [111.72996774103969, 899.9999999999999, 100.0]
I [109.28259103784066, 900.0, 900.0000000000001]
I [900.0, 110.11159887811019, 100.0]
I [899.9999999999999, 110.27284739706752, 900.0]
I [900.0, 900.0, 100.0]
I [900.0, 900.0, 900.0]
O [100.0, 100.0, 100.0]
O [100.0, 100.0, 900.0]
O [100.0, 900.0, 100.0]
O [100.0, 900.0, 900.0]
O [900.0, 100.0, 100.0]
O [900.0, 100.0, 900.0]
O [900.0, 900.0, 100.0]
O [900.0, 900.0, 900.0]
```

This is my working Picker part:

```
               Picker("Styles", selection: $selectedStyle) {
                    if selectedStyle == nil {
                        Text("\(currrentAxesPositionString)")
                            .tag(nil as StyleInstance?)
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(styles) { style in 
                        Text("\(designSpace.name(of: style))")
                            .tag(style as StyleInstance?)
                    }
                }
```

Because `StyleInstance.id` is defined as:

```
public var id: Int { hashValue }
public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        positionsOnAxes.forEach { pos in
            hasher.combine(pos.id)
        }
    }
```

I tried to change tag to `.tag(style.id as Int?)` but in this case `$selectedStyle` never change.

How to:

A: tag a Picker to have same results as `.tag(style as StyleInstance?)`? Is it possible without changing `$selectedStyle` type?

B: assign `styles = designSpace.styles` to have `styles == designSpace.styles`? How to use Force?

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
var bindingByID: Binding<Int?> {
        Binding(get: {selectedStyle?.id}, 
                set: {newID in selectedStyle = styles.first(where: {$0.id == newID})})
    }
```

And now I can tag by id. And changed

```
extension StyleInstance {
    public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
       lhs.id == rhs.id 
       && lhs.positionsOnAxes == rhs.positionsOnAxes
       && lhs.coordinates == rhs.coordinates
    }
}
```

It's always good to ask a wall.

More universal:

```
extension Binding 
{
    func by<ID, Wrapped>(path: KeyPath<Wrapped,ID>, array: [Wrapped]) -> Binding<ID?> 
    where ID : Equatable,
          Value == Optional<Wrapped>
    {
        return Binding<ID?>(get: {
            if let wrapped = wrappedValue {
                return wrapped[keyPath: path]
            }
            return nil
        }, 
                            set: { newId in 
            if let newId {
                wrappedValue = array.first(where: {element in
                    element[keyPath: path] == newId}) 
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and use:

```
Picker("Styles", selection: $selectedStyle.by(path: \.id, array: styles)) {....
```